# Como adicionar parâmetro Sender no onterminate de thread?

Tags: delphi, thread, firemonkey

Tenho uma thread que executa uma acão e no onterminate executa uma procedure secundaria.

Funciona assim:

```
procedure qualquer;
var
  Thread: TThread;
begin

  Thread.CreateAnonymousThread(
  procedure()
  begin

    excecuta ação  

  end;

  //como quero que fique - adicionando parametros
  Thread.OnTerminate:= concluiacao(parametro sender, outro parametro);

  //como faço
  Thread.OnTerminate:= concluiacao;

  Thread.Start;

end;
```

depois executo a segunda procedure

```
procedure concluiacao(Sender: TObject);
begin

  if TThread(Sender).FatalException <> nil then
  begin
    ShowMessage(TThread(Sender).FatalException.ToString);
    Exit;
  end
  else
    continua os processos normalmente;

end;
```

Gostria de enviar novos parametros no onterminate da thread, mas o primeiro parametro é um sender, e nao sei como envia-lo.

Comment: var
  Thread: TThread; --> aqui deverira ser um descendente de TThread.

Comment: O Sender é a própria Thread. Você pode declarar propriedades no descendente e ler seus valores no OnTerminate. Basta fazer um typecast.

Comment: Até tentei alguns códigos como concluiacao(Thread), concluiacao(TThread(Thread)) ou concluiacao(TObject(Thread)), mas não funcionaram.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34890222/createanonymousthread-with-parameters

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando métodos anônimos e atribuindo o evento OnTerminate, você não consegue obter nenhum outro parâmetro a não ser o Sender, pois o método que será atribuído deve corresponder exatamente à declaração da função OnTerminate esperada pelo Delphi.

Sendo assim, eu recomendaria a você declarar uma classe do tipo TThread e utilizar o Destroy do objeto para obter o término da thread e assim poderá controlar qualquer variável desejada.

Veja:

```
type
  TMinhaThread = class(TThread)
  private
    Parametro1: Integer;
    Parametro2: Boolean;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Th: TMinhaThread;
begin
    Th := TMinhaThread.Create(True); //criar a thread sem rodá-la
    Th.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    Th.Parametro1 := 100; //atribuir parâmetros internos
    Th.Start; //rodar a thread
end;

{ TMinhaThread }

procedure TMinhaThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;

  try
    {Fazer procedimentos da thread...}
    Parametro2 := True; //simulando parâmetro
    {...}
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Synchronize(procedure
      begin
        ShowMessage('Erro na thread: '+E.Message);
      end);
  end;
end;

destructor TMinhaThread.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
  //Aqui é o equivalente ao OnTerminate, porém você tem acesso as propriedades da thread

  if Parametro2 then
    Synchronize(procedure
    begin
      ShowMessage('...');
    end)
  else
    {outro procedimento};
end;
```